# Predict python dataframe

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Now I have a dataframe which contain annual records from 1959 to 2009. Could you please tell me how to use it to predict, say from 2010 to 2012?
Appreciation for any help!

Comment: How would you do the prediction *without* using Python?

Comment: I predict it will go up.

Comment: I mean just the most basic linear regression

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html

Comment: @Light: you should include it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/visualization.html) your data and have a look at it. You must then have a feeling of what's going on and also have a subjective prediction. 
If your data seems to be completely random, without any obvious trends, calculate its average and use it as a first-guess prediction. (For a fully random data, it will be the result from the linear regression as well).

You can then use linear regression, either with Pandas' [ols regression](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.8.1/computation.html#linear-and-panel-regression) tools, or numpy's [polyfit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html). Make sure you plot your data and the regression line to actually see how well your prediction is doing.

And don't expect to do a miracle with this method. Complicated things are much harder to predict than a linear regression, and 50-year-long processes, whatever they be, are usually complicated enough.